# PdfPHeaderCell right align content in text mode

Tags: itext

I have a table that has a couple of number columns. I can right align the row columns just fine, but I cannot right alight the header column. The reason, I think, is because the PdfPHeaderCell constructor does not accept a Phrase object so I have to use cell.addElement() which puts it into composite mode ignoring the alignment I specify.

The only way I have found to achieve the effect I am looking for is to create a paragraph, assign the alignment to it, and then put that in the header. That seems a little clunky to me since I dont need any characteristics of a paragraph, I just need to align it.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
  /**
   * Builds a basic header cell from the given string
   * 
   * @param content
   * @param alignment
   * @return PdfPHeaderCell
   */
  protected static PdfPHeaderCell getGenericHeaderCell(String content, Integer alignment)
  {
    PdfPHeaderCell cell = new PdfPHeaderCell();

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.add(new Phrase(content, TABLE_HEADER));
    if (alignment != null)
    {
      p.setAlignment(alignment);
    }

    cell.addElement(p);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    cell.setBorderColorBottom(TABLE_HEADER_BORDERCOLOR);
    cell.setBorderWidthBottom(1);
    cell.setPaddingTop(0);
    return cell;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this: you need a `Phrase` but you use a `Paragraph`, so you can replace:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Phrase(content, TABLE_HEADER));
if (alignment != null)
{
  p.setAlignment(alignment);
}
```

with:

```
Phrase p = new Phrase(content, TABLE_HEADER);
if (alignment != null)
{
  p.setAlignment(alignment);
}
```

The actual error in your code, is the fact that you use `addElement()`. You claim that you create a cell in text mode, but you forget that using `addElement()` makes the cell switch to composite mode.

You can fix this by replacing:

```
cell.addElement(p);
```

with:

```
cell.setPhrase(p);
```

That keeps the cell in text mode.